# Returning a message to a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session

I'm having some trouble returning a string to a component on a JSP page. I have built a very simple page as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<div id="logindiv" class="centered">
        <h1>DB Schema status</h1>
    <form action="DBConnectionTester" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="DB Username" style="text-align: center;">
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="DB Password" style="text-align: center;">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Get Schema" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <br>
        <br>
        <c:if test="${not empty rtnmsg}">
        <h6>${message}</h6>
        </c:if>
    </form>
    </div>
```

And the class behind it is as follows:

```
@WebServlet("/DBConnectionTester")
public class DBConnectionTester extends HttpServlet {

String rtnmsg = "";

DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  dbcon.usr = request.getParameter("usr");
  dbcon.pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");        
  dbcon.sampletest();
  rtnmsg = dbcon.rtnstr;
}
```

}

For clarification, DBConnection is as follows:

```
public class DBConnection {

public String usr;
public String pwd;

private static String mySQLCon = "jdbc:mysql://<REDACTED>zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
public String err;
public String stmt;

public String rtnstr;

void sampletest()
{
   try 
    {
    Connection mCon = DriverManager.getConnection(mySQLCon, usr, pwd);
    mCon.getSchema();
    err = "No connection issues";
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        err = e.toString();
    } 
   Date date = new Date();
   rtnstr = err + date.toString();
}       
}
```

Now, whenever I hit that submit button, my browser appears to access the class itself - that is to say, the URL in the browser is as follows: `http://<REDACTED>elasticbeanstalk.com/DBConnectionTester`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you think it should be a different URL. That's where the action of your form points to: `action="DBConnectionTester"` I think you need to step down, and learn how HTML forms work, and how HTTP works.

Comment: It will executed the form as asked `action="DBConnectionTester"`, so execute a POST request. Your servlet doesn't redirect to any page.

Comment: @AxelH I'm rather new to J2EE. Am I to believe that the action should point to the same page? I've had some trouble in finding understandable content on how `action` should be implemented.

Comment: You need to learn how HTML Forms works. Then how to use those with a Servlet. There are enough online course for that.